# What is the customary international law of transboundary fresh waters?

Tags: international-relations, international-law, water

I have a question concerning "water sharing between **two** countries that share a common river":

> - What is the country water percentage from which the river flows, is the percentage typically higher than the second country?
> - Is there a *clear* international law that dictates the percentages and legal rights of both countries?

---

Comment: What "should" be the case is discussion. What is is on topic. That's why I am editing your question. Also, it would be helpful for you to identify the question. The actual flow is significant.

Comment: That said, water allocation is both highly political and very much a concern that experts on policy care about.

Comment: thank you @AffableGeek, please tell me if it's clear. in lebanon we have a River Called **Assi**, this river originates from lebanon and passes through Syria. The syrian government said that we only have rights for *20%* of the water. Do you think it's fair? and is there an international law that explains what the percentage of water every country should have? not necessary between lebanon and syria but in general.

Comment: well @AffableGeek is there an international law on water allocation, between countries that share a common river? that's what i am trying to see

Comment: @AffableGeek it's a very hard subject. IT's really hard to find definitive percentages on how much water should be allocated. As u said it's really **Vague**

Comment: interesting article : http://www.transboundarywaters.orst.edu/publications/allocations/

Comment: I think it's generally decided by treaty. Israel, the PA, and Jordan signed a trilateral water distribution agreement about a week ago. Lebanon likely signed an agreement with Syria stating that only 20% of the Assi goes to Lebanon.

Comment: @Avi yes I heard about the Israeli water agreement. So it all depends on the countries, and how they agree on the water distribution. There is no internation law to decide the distribution.

Comment: @HaniGotc It's hardly definitive, but I don't know of relevant international law, and what I'm finding suggests there isn't any.

Comment: thank you @Avi sounds interesting. i am actually from Lebanon, i wonder if you are my neighbour. Hope we can have more discussions or debates.

Answer (score 7):

In most cases the boundary is drawn by treaty, but generally, the official boundary is the mid-point between the edge of the water. Each country will have certain rights delineated by treaty, such as who can fish in the river, and so on. There are notable exceptions, however, such as the Rio Grand, which is the boundary between the U.S. and Mexico, which according to treaty lies wholly within U.S. Territory.

It seems you are actually asking about water rights, however, and there is no established customary law. This is a major point of contention for down stream countries, which have historically relied upon water from a source, which gets dammed by the upstream country. Because there is no general agreement, and there is unlikely to be one, the upstream country has a significant advantage because of possession.

For example, the Colorado River between the U.S. and Mexico does not reach Mexico at all during many times of the year. Mexico doesn't like that, but the U.S. refuses to do anything about it.